# Adding custom backgrounds to D3.js bar graph

Tags: html, animation, background, d3.js, bar-chart

I'm fairly new to d3.js and I'm building a bar graph in D3.js.

I'm trying to make the background three different colors to break the x axis into distinct three zones (low, medium, and high). I figure I should be appending some `<g>`elements but I'm not sure how to place them in this case.

The site is up [here](http://www.hungergames.miketissenbaum.com/patchGraph.html):

[image]

Not sure if providing more of the code would help

Comment: You can simply add three 'rect' elements before adding the rest of the chart elements to serve as background 'regions'

Comment: That worked sort of, but now the first three bars of the graph are gone. I also get some weird overlapping (I figure that's the padding between bars, but I'm not sure how to adjust for it)

Comment: I fixed the overlapping - I just needed to adjust the widths of the rectangles by the padding so that's fine. The issue now is that the "missing" bars actually seem to have been replaced by the first three bars that I inserted

Comment: Ok just as a follow up for anyone else trying this. For what I'm trying to do what Josh suggests won't work unless I'm missing something this is basically because the bar charts are rectangles and in my code to draw the bars I use:

`svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")`

So I end up selecting ALL the rectangles in the DOM, this means that the first 3 are where the first 3 bars of the chart should be (but are overwritten by the backgrounds. So you need to do something other than what I did (or find a way to skip the first 3 bars when generating the chart)

Comment: In this case, I would suggest adding a class attribute to the data bars, so you can select only them later, i.e.:  `..append("rect").attr("style", "bar")` and selecting them later via: `d3.selectAll("rect.bar").transition..`

Comment: This worked Josh - thanks! Posted my code in case anyone else needs it or will find it useful because I also had to deal with mouseovers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on what Josh suggested in the comments but I thought I'd add my code since I also had to deal with a mouseover and so this created some extra challenges too.

One thing worth mentioning is that there isn't a z-index with SVGs so you have to put the new background shades in first and then do the chart bars (which is also why you have to give the rectangles for the bar chart a new name, as per Josh's suggestion)

```
        svg.append("rect")
            .attr("y", padding)
            .attr("x", padding)
            .attr("width", 200)
            .attr("height", h -padding*2)
            .attr("fill", "rgba(0,255,0, 0.3")
            .attr("class", "legendBar")

        svg.append("rect")
            .attr("y", padding)
            .attr("x", padding +200)
            .attr("width", 200)
            .attr("height", h -padding*2)
            .attr("fill", "rgba(0,0,255, 0.3")
            .attr("class", "legendBar")

        svg.append("rect")
            .attr("y", padding)
            .attr("x", padding +400)
            .attr("width", 200)
            .attr("height", h -padding*2)
            .attr("fill", "rgba(255,0,0, 0.3")
            .attr("class", "legendBar")

        svg.selectAll("rect.bars")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bars")
            .attr("x", 0 + padding)
            .attr("y", function(d, i){
                return yScale(i);
            })
            .attr("width", function(d) {
                return xScale(d.values[0]);
            })
            .attr("height", yScale.rangeBand())



.on("mouseover", function(d){

                var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) + yScale.rangeBand() /2
                var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x")) /2 + w /2;

                d3.select("#tooltip")
                    .style("left", "660px")
                    .style("top", "140px")
                    .select("#strat")
                    .text(d.values[3]);

                d3.select("#tooltip")
                    .select("#graph")
                    .attr("src", "img/cpg.jpg");

                d3.select("#tooltip")
                    .select("#studentName")
                    .text(d.name);

                d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);
            })

            .on("mouseout", function() {
                d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);
            });
```